# Practical communication example for a data rate scenario

Tags: computer-networks

Having difficulty with the following question.

I can answer parts I and II but having trouble finding a practical example.

Question:

> Compute the maximum data rate of the following communication links;
>
> I) 4000Hz bandwidth and a signal to noise ratio(SNR) of 20dB;
>
> II) noiseless channel of 2.4GHz bandwidth with 64 signalling levels;
>
> **Provide a practical communication example for each scenario.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is a CS question within [the scope of the site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreed; this seems to be a question of the form "where would you use *technology* X" while we deal with *concepts*. Community votes, please!

Comment: Apologies, which forum do you believe this question belongs, I thought this site was for Computer Science Students. Is the question not an aspect of Computer Science?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4kHz bandwidth and 20dB SNR is telephone communication.
2.4GHz with 64 signaling levels is WiFi with 64QAM if I understood correctly. In that case bitrate is 6 * baud.